# accept JSON in coffeescript as AJAX response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, coffeescript

I have rails controller:

```
class TrafficVolumeController < ApplicationController
  def test
    render json: Traffic.all
  end
end
```

I can see it returns json:
[image]

On this AJAX request:

```
 $.ajax '/traffic_volume/test',
    type: 'GET'
    dataType: 'json'
    json: true
    success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
     $('body').append "Successful AJAX call: #{data}"
```

But data is of Anything type and in browser I can see:

[image]

So the question is how to work with this `data` parameter. Do I have to cast it to other type or I need to change HTTP headers in request or something in rails controller. Really need your help as I've spent so many time on this already. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you observe on the page, is the default string representation of object, which is not very helpful.

Try this one, should be *much* better:

```
 console.log "Successful AJAX call: ", data
```

That `data` of yours, it's an array, right? If so, this should work as well

```
 $('body').append(data[0].year) # or whatever you were going to do 
                                # in the first place
```

Comment: thanks! Yeah, it's array. I was a bit confused by Anything type. Didn't get at once that I can work with data object like with array